ubuntu bluetooth network card(bt0) how to access wan?
Bluetooth ips profile cannot access wan and can only communicate within the local area network. I am now using ubuntu as the router role of ipsp. Ubuntu has two network cards, a wifi network card(wlp5s0) and a bluetooth network card(bt0). The wifi network card can access wan. My current requirement is that my bluetooth network card (6lowpan 6LBR) can also access wan. I am a newbie when it comes to network layer things. Can anyone give me some advice?
My current idea is to route the data of the Bluetooth network card to the WiFi network card so that the 6LBR role can access the wan. I am not sure if my direction is correct. Here are some attempts I made
Manually assign a global address to the Bluetooth network card (bt0), and its prefix is ​​the same as the WiFi global address prefix. The following is the output of ifconfig
root@SH-SC1015:~# ifconfig 
    bt0: flags=4161<UP,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1280
            inet6 2408:8459:3030:9afe::2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
            inet6 fe80::30d1:6bff:fef8:5b40  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
            unspec 30-D1-6B-F8-5B-40-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 1000  (UNSPEC)
            RX packets 6  bytes 220 (220.0 B)
            RX errors 0  dropped 3  overruns 0  frame 0
            TX packets 114  bytes 8752 (8.7 KB)
            TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp3s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 8c:16:45:d7:8e:d4  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 770523  bytes 120329227 (120.3 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 770523  bytes 120329227 (120.3 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp5s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.14.254  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.14.255
        inet6 fe80::8be2:ae9:5a6a:5230  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2408:8459:3030:9afe:ec76:5170:2f87:41bc  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2408:8459:3030:9afe:c2e0:549d:78b5:177a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 30:d1:6b:f8:5b:3f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 185238  bytes 60240240 (60.2 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 662479  bytes 372008647 (372.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

root@SH-SC1015:~# ip -6 route show
::1 dev lo proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
2408:8459:3030:9afe::/64 dev bt0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
2408:8459:3030:9afe::/64 dev wlp5s0 proto ra metric 600 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev bt0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev wlp5s0 proto kernel metric 600 pref medium
default dev wlp5s0 metric 1024 pref medium
default via fe80::5456:b7ff:fe9e:7d3 dev wlp5s0 proto ra metric 20600 pref high

root@SH-SC1015:~# echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/forwarding

root@SH-SC1015:~# iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlp5s0 -j MASQUERADE

root@SH-SC1015:~# iptables -A FORWARD -i bt0 -o wlp5s0 -j ACCEPT

root@SH-SC1015:~# iptables -A FORWARD -i wlp5s0 -o bt0 -j ACCEPT

root@SH-SC1015:~# iptables -L -v -n

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 3026 packets, 392K bytes)

pkts bytes target prot opt in out source destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)

pkts bytes target prot opt in out source destination

0 0 ACCEPT all -- bt0 wlp5s0 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0

0 0 ACCEPT all -- wlp5s0 bt0 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 3197 packets, 589K bytes)

pkts bytes target prot opt in out source destination

root@SH-SC1015:~#

I have already forwarded data between bt0 and wlp5s0, but ping6 -I bt0 8.8.8.8 still does not work, ping6 -I wlp5s0 8.8.8.8 works
